# TEAM RISP scoring average

Tags: mlb

Is there an advanced statistic that measures a team scoring a run with 2 outs & RISP? Average or some metric.

Comment: What do you mean by "measures a team scoring a run"? The historical probability of a team scoring a run with 2 outs and RISP is trivial to calculate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there a statistic that calculates the percentage of success when a team scoring one or more runs w/ two outs & RISP.